# How to remove only some facet labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Using `facet_wrap`, is it possible to remove only some facet labels? 
In the following example I'd like the Species label to only appear in the first column of each row. I know I can use the `labeller` function but not how to change individual labels.

```
data(iris)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- iris %>%
  gather(var, val, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) 

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = val)) +
  facet_wrap(Species~var)
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing the `labeller` argument perhaps. I just saw you mentioned it in your post. My bad!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not at all perfect, but I am posting this hoping it's still better than nothing.

The use of `as_labeller()` and `labeller()` may get you what you need.

**Update**

Easiest solution was to split `Species` and `var` in two `labellers` functions.

```
facet_labeller_top <- function(variable, value) {
  c(
    "Setosa", 
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "Versicolor", 
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "Virginica", 
    "",
    "",
    ""
  )
}

facet_labeller_bottom <- function(variable, value) {
  c(
    "Petal.Length", 
    "Petal.Width",
    "Sepal.Length",
    "Sepal.Width",
    "Petal.Length", 
    "Petal.Width",
    "Sepal.Length",
    "Sepal.Width",
    "Petal.Length", 
    "Petal.Width",
    "Sepal.Length",
    "Sepal.Width"
  )
}
```

Result:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = val)) +
  facet_wrap(Species~var, labeller = labeller(Species=as_labeller(facet_labeller_top),
                                              var = as_labeller(facet_labeller_bottom)))
```

[image]

Data example:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- iris %>%
  gather(var, val, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

Comment: Why would I see this error: `Error in labeller(Species = as_labeller(facet_labeller_top), var = as_labeller(facet_labeller_bottom)) : 
  unused arguments (Species = as_labeller(facet_labeller_top), var = as_labeller(facet_labeller_bottom))`?

Comment: Which version of `ggplot2` are you on? On `3.2.1` currently works. Try with a clean env if it still fails for you.

Comment: Thanks! It was a version issue, updating solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand well but I will try:

You can use facet_grid instead of facet_wrap

this is the code:

```
data(iris)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- iris %>%
  gather(var, val, Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) 

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = val)) +
  facet_grid(Species~var)
```

This is the result: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. As I said, I want the Species label to appear only in the first column of each row of facets.