# How to control which facet_wrap labels are displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

In the following use of `facet_wrap`, both the `year` and `model` are displayed in the plot labels.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer=='audi')%>%
  ggplot(aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = model)) +
  facet_wrap(year~model)
```

[image]

We already colored the points by `model` and it is shown in the legend, so we dont really need `model` in each facet label. How can we remove `model` from the labels?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178285/how-to-remove-only-some-facet-labels and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114850/only-show-one-variable-label-in-facet-wrap-strip-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to adjust the labeler function to only extract labels for the first variable. You can do that with

```
mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer=='audi')%>%
  ggplot(aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = model)) +
  facet_wrap(~year+model, labeller=function(x) {x[1]})
```

The other way is to create an interaction variable so you are only faceting on one variable and then you can change the labeller to strip out the name of the second value. That would look like this

```
mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer=='audi')%>%
  ggplot(aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = model)) +
  facet_wrap(~interaction(year,model), labeller=as_labeller(function(x) gsub("\\..*$", "", x)))
```

[image: plot without model name in facet strip]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define a custom labeller function. I found the explanation in the docs for "labellers" of what the input and output format needs to be a bit confusing. So hopefully this simple example helps others.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer=='audi')%>%
  ggplot(aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = model)) +
  facet_wrap(year~model, 
             labeller = function(df) {
               list(as.character(df[,1]))
             })
```